# Error on get image from gallery

Tags: android

I create a code that access gallery, choose a image, and crop image, after it, the code call a function that save the file, this function give ,e a error:

> at com.alexandreccarmo.beerin.user.activities.UserPerfilActivity.onSelectFromGalleryResult(UserPerfilActivity.java:396)
>                                                                                   at com.alexandreccarmo.beerin.user.activities.UserPerfilActivity.onActivityResult(UserPerfilActivity.java:238)

This error refer this line:

**bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());**

This is the function:

```
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) throws IOException {

    Bitmap bm=null;
    if (data != null) {
        bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());


        Bitmap thumbnail = bm;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

        //File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.jpg");

        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);

    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UserPerfilActivity.this, "", "Alterando a foto...", true);

}
```

How can I fix it?

This is the complete code:

```
private void galleryIntent()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//

    //crop
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 96);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 96);
    // retrieve data on return
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);

}

   @Override
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,                   Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        imagePath = this.destinationUpload.getAbsolutePath();
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                try {
                    onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

complete stack trace:

```
06-09 12:45:43.627 21600-21600/com.alexandreccarmo.beerin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.alexandreccarmo.beerin/com.alexandreccarmo.beerin.user.activities.UserPerfilActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.Bitmap cannot be cast to android.net.Uri
  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3205)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3248)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:140)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.Bitmap cannot be cast to android.net.Uri
  at com.alexandreccarmo.beerin.user.activities.UserPerfilActivity.onSelectFromGalleryResult(UserPerfilActivity.java:396)
  at com.alexandreccarmo.beerin.user.activities.UserPerfilActivity.onActivityResult(UserPerfilActivity.java:238)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5390)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3201)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3248) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:140) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
06-09 12:50:43.662 21600-21600/com.alexandreccarmo.beerin I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21600 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Android [does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one, rather than assuming that those extras will work on all devices. Beyond that, please edit your question and post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Sorry, I dont use "com.android.camera.action.CROP". Its only a test. But the error is the same. I edited my post.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Hmmmm... which is the line that is throwing the error? I am not certain which is line 396 in `UserPerfilActivity.java`, and it is not obvious where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your stack trace...

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.Bitmap cannot be cast to android.net.Uri

Based on Android's documentation:

> getBitmap Added in API level 1
>   `Bitmap getBitmap (ContentResolver cr, Uri url)`

It looks like what you are passing in to the 2nd parameter is actually a `android.graphics.Bitmap` object instead of a `android.net.Uri`.

Which means that your `Intent` data is actually a `Bitmap` and consequently `data.getData()` is returning a `Bitmap` which the method doesn't like.

You should directly be able to assign `bm = data.getData()` as that is what the Gallery Selection `Intent` is returning.